# Ask & answer questions about niche programming language

Tags: discussion, questions

**Background**

Okay, so I've figured out that obscure programming language are okay to ask about on Stack Overflow.

And, I know a bit about the language [Arden Syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arden_syntax) used to code Medical Logic Modules (MLMs). But I am knowledgeable only within the context of Allscripts [Sunrise Clinical Manager (SCM)](http://www.allscripts.com/en/solutions/acute-solutions/ehr/show.html).

I don't need to ask questions for my own benefit, but would like to see MLM coding resources become more widely available on the internet and am considering doing some seed work by asking and answering some questions on Stack Overflow.

**Questions**

1. Is it okay to ask (and answer) questions about a programming language that may be specific in its flavor to a single manufacturer's product? I don't even know how much Arden is used in other products besides SCM, and in what ways it differs from other products. So my answers will likely step outside the bounds of plain Arden and be slanted toward SCM.
2. Assuming yes, should I tag these questions with all of [mlm](/questions/tagged/mlm), [scm](/questions/tagged/scm), and [arden-syntax](/questions/tagged/arden-syntax)? The language is actually *Arden Syntax*, but *MLM* is often used as a synonym despite not being the name of the language (as in "write an MLM" or "MLM coder"), and *SCM* is a product name. But, I see parallels to for example [sql-server-2008](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008) which is a particular manufacturer's product. Except, SCM itself isn't something that would necessarily bring to mind "ahhh, you're talking about Arden Syntax, of course!"

All in all aside from the tagging aspect I'm guessing I'm probably in the clear, but thought I'd go ahead and ask before I start creating questions and answers with new tags no one has ever heard of.

**Update**

See the new meta question, [discussion on tags and my first Q&As in this area](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175015/critique-of-new-programming-language-first-qas).

Comment: For the second point, I'm not positive, but I would say that you should tag only with the name of the actual language. There can be synonyms later if a lot of people use `mlm` when they mean `arden-syntax`.

Comment: [Asking questions about uncommon languages](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148280/2509) is very similar.

Comment: @dmckee Maybe the first bullet point, but the second one is completely different.

Comment: Yes. That's why I didn't vote to close.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, it's fine, there is already an [android](/questions/tagged/android) tag  (Google), and a bunch of other tags that could be considered a "manufacturer's product"

Also, you may get a bunch of tumbleweed for doing this kind of thing, and end up answering your own questions a lot, but a community (for the tech) and a Q&A place has to start somewhere.

I would avoid using abbreviations for obscure terms such as "Medical Logic Modules" (MLM), instead use the entire name ([medical-logic-modules](/questions/tagged/medical-logic-modules), [sunrise-clinical-manager](/questions/tagged/sunrise-clinical-manager)).  *SCM* is already an overused abbreviation, and actually aliases to [version-control](/questions/tagged/version-control) on SO because it already means "source control management".

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful and will save me a bunch of time retagging. Is there a way to add synonyms myself? It looks like Allscripts changed their product name to "Sunrise Acute Care", too... but people have had the old product name for a long time.

Comment: Of course, Android is an operating system, where one would expect to be able to write programs in a programming language...

Comment: For what it's worth, I've been "instructed" to use a single tag and settled on [tag:arden-syntax]. See [this thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175015/critique-of-new-programming-language-first-qas).